# Android - Open native android apps from PHONEGAP

Tags: android, cordova

Does anyone knows how can I open a native android app from a button in phonegap?
I'm creating an Activity that opens your phone apps so I need something to open the apps. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a plugin, that starts an Intent.

This blog may be a good entry:
http://tannerburson.com/blog/2012/05/28/IntentChooser-my-first-PhoneGap-Cordova-plugin/

Answer (score 1):

Well if you want to open any native Android app then you'll need to [write a plugin](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/guide_plugin-development_index.md.html#Plugin%20Development%20Guide) to call the apps Intent.

Although if you just want to open the Dialer app you can do:

```
<button onclick="document.location='tel:'">Phone</button>
```

and if can specify a phone number as well:

```
<button onclick="document.location='tel:411'">Phone</button>
```